# Dynamicaly add georeferensed rasters to arcgis map

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I want to dynamicaly add gepreferenced raster datasets on arcgis map in wpf application. I tried to do it with arcgis sdk runtime for wpf, but i have only basic(free) license(and only standart license allow to add raster datasets). Is it possible without standart license for sdk or arcgis server? Maybe some opensource dlls?

Comment: do you wish to dynamically georeference rasters or just dynamically add already georeferenced images from a server?

Comment: Images are already georeferenced. For example, its maybe aerial photographs in geotiff

Comment: you need to host your geo ref image as a service on a arcgis server and then use the resulting url from the server in the WPF application. If you are interested in this method, I can share some details on how to do that.

Comment: Its a good way, i search a method, which doesnt require arcgis server or event internet connection